# Javascript == not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
var data =
    [
        {"id" : "1", "name" : "Computer Components", "Parent_ID" : "-1"},
        {"id" : "2", "name" : "Processors", "Parent_ID" : "1"},
        {"id" : "3", "name" : "Graphics Cards", "Parent_ID" : "1"},
        {"id" : "4", "name" : "Motherboard", "Parent_ID" : "1"},
        {"id" : "5", "name" : "Power Supply", "Parent_ID" : "1"},
        {"id" : "6", "name" : "Intel Platform", "Parent_ID" : "4"},
        {"id" : "7", "name" : "AMD Platform", "Parent_ID" : "4"},
        {"id" : "8", "name" : "z270", "Parent_ID" : "6"},
        {"id" : "9", "name" : "z170", "Parent_ID" : "6"},
        {"id" : "10", "name" : "x299", "Parent_ID" : "6"},
        {"id" : "11", "name" : "x99", "Parent_ID" : "6"},
        {"id" : "12", "name" : "z399", "Parent_ID" : "7"},
        {"id" : "13", "name" : "z370", "Parent_ID" : "7"}
    ];
```

I am using the following function to find all the objects that have the same `Parent_ID` as `element_ID`:

```
function getChildren(element_ID) {
    var i, children = [];
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (element_ID == data[i].parent_ID) {
            children.push(data[i].id);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
```

However the function returns children as an empty array when I try `getChildren(1);`

This doesn't make sense to me as there are clearly several objects in the data that have a Parent_ID of 1. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The objects have a key `Parent_ID` but your function is checking for `parent_ID` (lowercase `p`). Could that be the issue?

Comment: Try using `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @RaphaelSauer Good practice, but irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @RaphaelSauer Nah, that won't work, because the objects have a string and the function is receiving a number. `===` will fail on the check for an identical type.

Comment: @rickdenhaan That was indeed it. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine when the typo is fixed -> https://jsfiddle.net/0w5k3ahu/

Comment: @FarasatAhmed Sweet, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object properties are case-sensitive in Javascript.

Your objects have a property called `Parent_ID`, but your function is checking for `parent_ID`. Change that check to match the uppercase "P":

```
if (element_ID == data[i].Parent_ID) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix. You're accessing `Parent_ID` incorrectly, you're using a lowercase `p`

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Computer Components",
    "Parent_ID": "-1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Processors",
    "Parent_ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Graphics Cards",
    "Parent_ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Motherboard",
    "Parent_ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Power Supply",
    "Parent_ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Intel Platform",
    "Parent_ID": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "AMD Platform",
    "Parent_ID": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "z270",
    "Parent_ID": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "z170",
    "Parent_ID": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "x299",
    "Parent_ID": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "x99",
    "Parent_ID": "6"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "z399",
    "Parent_ID": "7"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "z370",
    "Parent_ID": "7"
  }
];

function getChildren(id) {
  var children = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (id === data[i]['Parent_ID']) {
      children.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return children;
}


console.log(getChildren("-1"));
```